# How to change a variable every iteration of a loop (Java)

Tags: java, variables, loops, char, int

How can I have my variables change after every loop. I need the stated arraylist variables to go where the code is marked "HERE".

```
//variables i need to cycle through
static ArrayList<Integer> one1,two1,one2,two2=new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<word1[i].length();j++){
    if (word1[i].charAt(j)=='-'){
      HERE.add(j);
    } else if (word1[i].charAt(j)!='-') {
      HERE.add(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way i could do this without dozens of lines of code?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a map of lists or other data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `here` method that adds to multiple lists for you like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        here(1, l1, l2, l3);
    }

    public static void here(Integer integer, List<Integer>... lists) {
        for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
            list.add(integer);
        }
    }

}
```

The `...` is called a varargs and [you can learn more about it here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)  Just call this every time you have `HERE.add` in your current code like this: `here(j, one1, two1, one2, two2)`

But I think you're probably doing something wrong here.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your Lists into an array.

```
for(List<Integer> HERE: new List<Integer>[]{ one1,two1,one2,two2})
```